# Why does udev rule not work on `DEVPATH=="/kernel"`?

Tags: udev, sysfs

I'm testing udev rules with a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-test.rules`.

This line:

```
DEVPATH=="/devices/system/node/node0", ATTR{hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages}="4"
```

makes `/sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages` be `4`.

But this line:

```
DEVPATH=="/kernel/mm", ATTR{hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages}="4"
```

does not affect `/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages`.

Neither does this line:

```
DEVPATH=="/kernel", ATTR{mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages}="4"
```

(Even rebooting does not work.)

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/sys/devices/system/node/node0` represents a NUMA hardware node that may accept a command to go into an offline state independent of the rest of the system. So it can be the subject of *udev events*, which can trigger actions based on *udev rules*.

`/sys/kernel/mm` represents no particular hardware: it is just a place for general memory management parameters of the kernel. It is present as soon as the kernel starts up and cannot go away, so there will be no udev events referencing it. And when there are no udev events, udev rules cannot be triggered.

Alternatively, you can say that only things under `/sys/devices` can have udev rules associated with them. `/sys/kernel` is not under `/sys/devices`.

Using udev rules to manipulate general memory management parameters would be rather unusual. `/etc/sysctl.conf[.d]` would be a more standard place for customizing them.